# Does analytical political philosophy discuss both capitalism and communism as an inheritence of Christianity?

Tags: political-philosophy, continental-philosophy, analytic-philosophy

[John Gray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_N._Gray), discusses in his book, *Black Mass*, the similarities between both Capitalism and Communism in terms of Christianity in a Post-Christian Europe - he calls them both Political Religion:

> He identifies the Enlightenment as the point at which the Christian doctrine of salvation was taken over by secular idealism and became a political religion with universal emancipation as its aim. Communism, fascism and "global democratic capitalism" are characterised by Gray as Enlightenment 'projects' which have led to needless suffering, in Gray's view, as a result of their ideological allegiance to this religion

I tend to associate this with continental thinking, though this might be just a habit of thought - is it in fact also a position thats discussed in Analytical Philosophy?

To elaborate a little further, AC Grayling in this [review](http://rationalist.org.uk/1423) takes him to task for emptying the word religion of meaning as he appears to apply it gratuitously to any ideology.

> Gray begins by calling any view or outlook a “religion”. Everything is a religion: Torquemada’s Catholicism, the pluralism and empiricism of 18th-century philosophers, liberalism, Stalinism. He speaks of “secular religion” and “political religion”. This empties the word “religion” of any meaning,

and

> But in making a nonsense of the word “religion” Gray blurs and blends just where important distinctions are required. A religion is a view which essentially premises commitment to belief in the existence of supernatural agencies in the universe, almost always conceived as having intentions and expectations regarding human beings.

But this appears to be mis-reading Grays argument. In Classical Economics we have the *Invisible Hand* of Adam Smiths which in todays terminology is the price-mechanism; but in Adams Smiths conception one also note that it is the hand of Providence. One thinks here Michaelangelos fresco where God breathes life into Adam symbolised by the (near) touching of hands.

From Smiths, *The Theory of Moral Sentiments*

> The produce of the soil maintains at all times nearly that number of inhabitants which it is capable of maintaining. The rich only select from the heap what is most precious and agreeable...they divide with the poor the produce of all their improvements. They are led by an *invisible hand* to make nearly the same distribution of the necessaries of life, which would have been made, had the earth been divided into equal portions among all its inhabitants, and thus without intending it, without knowing it, advance the interest of the society, and afford means to the multiplication of the species. When *Providence* divided the earth among a few lordly masters, it neither forgot nor abandoned those who seemed to have been left out in the partition.”

moreover, its possible that he derived this phrase from Saint Augustine, who had written:

> “God’s hand is his power, which moves visible things by invisible means.”

In Marxs political economy, it is Hegels mystical conception of the Geist which drives Humanity forward via a *dialectic|*. Though in Marx's conception it is articulated in the class composition of society and the material conditions for production. This is what makes empirical and thus *scientific* - in his sense.

In both of these conceptions we have something over and above nature - that is supernatural. Of course in todays scientific & rationalist discourse, this supernatural element is hidden.

**EDIT**

According to Mircea Eliade, a historian of religions:

> "[Marxism] takes up and carries on one of the great eschatological myths of the Middle Eastern and Mediterranean world, namely: the redemptive part to be played by the Just (the 'elect', the 'anointed', the 'innocent', the 'missioners', in our own days the proletariat), whose sufferings are invoked to change the ontological status of the world."

Comment: I would not call Grayling's comment a misreading. On reading the bits you quoted of Gray, I felt exactly as Grayling did. AFAIK, Adam Smith's *invisible hand* was just a metaphor. Isn't proclaiming its allusion to Providence merely a speculative opinion? In fact, if we were just as ready to abuse words, what's to stop us from calling Gray's own ideology a religion?

Comment: @prash: maybe more of a cult, than a religion;). Well one could call it a metaphor if Adam Smith was a secular thinker - but I'm not sure that it is true. I've edited the question to include the quote from Smith.

Comment: Thanks for the updates to the question. Coming to "cult"... well, *anything* could turn into a cult even if it did not start out as one. (Do you remember the Pythagorean's hatred of the idea of irrational numbers?) Again, this is unhelpful for a discussion. I'm guessing you did not mean to consider Adam Smith and Karl Marx as cult founders. If we were to abuse the meaning of "cult", no one is immune to being accused of being either a cult member or a cult founder, including you, me, and John Gray.

Comment: I'd suggest that Gray is using religion in the way an anthropologist might use it in terms of describing the world view of a people. But he doesn't use the word world-view, because of his rhetorical style, but also because it links up with Christianity - also religion has an emotional component that is missing from the rather anodyne word world-view.

Comment: If capitalism and communism are inheritances of Christianity, is mathematics an inheritance of Platonism?

Comment: @de Beaudrap: Platonism was fashioned out of Platos theory of Forms but isn't identical with it.

Comment: I think the ultimate gauge is that Religions believe in a God, discourage from greed and preoccupation with material pursuits, they encourage self-sacrifice, humility and charity, whereas selfishness and materialistic greed are integral to Capitalism, and in Marxism the kind of practical materialism of Capitalism is even substantiated as a philosophy. So I believe these ideologies are the farthest thing from religion. They are completely void of the spiritual substance of religions.